# ask Baby Rudin chapter 3 exercise 4

Tags: analysis

Find the upper and lower limits of the sequence {$s_n$} defined by

$$s_1=0; s_{2m}=\frac{s_{2m-1}}{2}; s_{2m+1}=\frac{1}{2}+s_{2m}$$.

I don't know how to solve but I understand the solution. The only concern is we find the limit of even terms and odd terms of sequence. How can we guarantee they must be upper and lower limits of the original sequence? I don't know we have such a property.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split $\{s_n\}$ into odd and even terms and we obtain two convergent sequences. If $\{t_n\}$ is a convergent subsequence of $\{s_n\}$, then since $\{t_n\}$ contains infinitely many even terms or odd terms, it converges to the limit of even sequence or odd sequence, respectively, by remark after definition 3.5. Hence the set $E$ defined as in definition 3.16 contains only two numbers, i.e., the limit of even sequence and the limit of odd sequence.

Comment: So next time when I am asked to find upper and lower limit, I first go ahead to look ta odd terms and even terms of the sequence. If both are convergent to different limit, say, a and b. Then the bigger one is upper limit, the less one is lower limit. Am I right?

Comment: No. Consider a sequence $\{s_n\}$ where $s_1,s_4,...$ converges, $s_2,s_5,...$ converges, and $s_3,s_6,...$ converges.

Comment: Then I am confused again. When we find the odd subsequence converges to a, the even subsequence converges to b, why we can claim that min(a,b) is the lower limit?

Comment: Because then the set of all $x$ such that $s_{n_k}\rightarrow x$ contains only $a$ and $b$. My example contains at most 3 elements.

Comment: The key point is the remark after definition 3.5

Comment: Here is another example. Consider the sequence $1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,...$.